# How to setup IPtables to allow capture network traffic from a virtualbox VM configured with NAT

Tags: linux, networking, virtualbox, iptables

I would like to have a VirtualBox virtual machine that can't get online.  I want to be able to monitor all network traffic attempts from the Linux host.

So, if the virtual machine attempts to make a SYN out to a random IP (that it can't route to) the Linux host will be able to see this traffic with tcpdump running.  I believe I will need to setup some type of forwarding rules with IPtables.

Has anyone accomplished this?

Answer (score 0):

INPUT DROP
OUTPUT DROP
FORWARD DROP

If desired you can add separate rules for your internal networks you want to allow.

All traffic is dropped on the monitoring PC

Then monitor using snort.  snort should still be able to monitor the network since it operates more like tcpdump internally.

Answer (score 0):

If your vm is behind a NAT and not in bridged mode, it is going to be able to sniff only the traffict on its network segment... which probably will be only the traffic of itself and your host on that interface... you can't sniff the traffic of the network on which your host is. To do this you will need to configure your vm as bridged.